# Asymptotic notation big(O) and Big(Omega)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

> f(n) = 6*2^n  + n^2
>
> big(O) = 2^n
>
> big(Omega) = 2^n

In above equation both big(O) and big(Omega) has same value. If big (O) is upper bound and big(omega) is lower bound shouldn't big(omega) = n^2. Why the both have same value?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not 6 * 2^n? If it's 62^n, then this is just wrong, IMHO.

Comment: @AmiTavory thanx.corrected it.

Comment: Short answer: because n² is neglectible compared to 2^n.

Comment: Doesn't this belong to math.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @MayeulC It's not a programming question, but it's fundamental to understanding algorithms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's true that *O* and *Ω* are upper and lower bounds, respectively, but they are more similar to *≤* and *≥* than to *<* and *>*. Just like it's possible that, simultaneously *a ≥ b* and *a ≤ b* (without contradiction), so can a function be both *O* and *Ω* of a different function (in fact, that's one of the ways to define *Θ*).

Here, for large enough *n*,

- *6 2<sup>n</sup> + n<sup>2</sup> ≤ 12 2<sup>n</sup>* so *6 2<sup>n</sup> + n<sup>2</sup>* grows at most (up to a multiplicative constant)like *2<sup>n</sup>* does (it is *O* of it).
- Conversely, *6 2<sup>n</sup> + n<sup>2</sup> ≥ 0.1 2<sup>n</sup>* so *6 2<sup>n</sup> + n<sup>2</sup>* grows at least (up to a multiplicative constant) like *2<sup>n</sup>* does (it is *Ω* of it).

Note that you don't have to use the same multiplicative constants. The conclusion is that *6 2<sup>n</sup> + n<sup>2</sup> = Θ( 2<sup>n</sup>)*

Comment: You confuse n² and 2^n.

Comment: I think that's _6 *2^n_, which is actually quite different.

Comment: @MayeulC Thanks, I had a typo in the answer, but your comment caught me in the middle of the correction. Is it OK now? Thanks again.

Comment: @AmiTavory, yes, that's much better :) Sorry for my redundant comment here, YvesDaoust 's comment wasn't there when I loaded the page.